# fgets не читает файл

Tags: c, winapi

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему fgets не считывает строки файла и сразу возвращает null?

```
BOOL CALLBACK DlgProcMenu(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM 
lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
        case WM_INITDIALOG:
        {   
            FILE * fp;
            CHAR name[] = "server.ini";
            CHAR buff[64] = { 0 };
            if ((fp = fopen(name, "r+")) == NULL)
                 if ((fp = fopen(name, "a+")) == NULL)
                 {
                      MessageBox(hwnd, "Не удалось создать server.ini", 
                      "Внимание", MB_OK);
                       break;
                 }

            for (int i = IDC_DBEDIT1; i < IDC_DBEDIT5; i++)
            {
                SetDlgItemText(hwnd, i, fgets(buff, 64, fp));
                ZeroMemory(buff, sizeof(buff));
            }
            break;
        }
        case WM_CLOSE: //обработчик закрытия
            EndDialog(hwnd, 0);
            return FALSE;
        default:
            break;
     }
     return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Пустой файл, например? Только что созданный вторым `fopen`?

Comment: файл создал и заполнил вручную

Comment: Да мало ли... "Создал и заполнил вручную" в одной директории, а попытки чтения делаются в другой. Какой из `fopen` сработал - почему в вопросе нет этой информации???

Comment: Здоровья тебя и добра! Прописал полный путь - заработало! Но почему так, если они в одной директории?! (экзешник и server.ini)

Comment: Смотрите функцию - текущий каталог. http://www.codenet.ru/progr/cpp/sprd/getcwd.php